# Exception handling in Jest/Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am testing my React components using Jest/Enzyme.

In some of the test cases, the test fails with some exception.
What is a sane/standard way to handle error in Jest/Enzyme instead of breaking the test case?

e.g - the following case should pass if the 'Grid' component does not get any data as parameter.However, it fails with an exception which is being thrown out of the Grid component.

```
test('Grid does not render without data',()=>{
const wrapper=shallow(<Grid/>);
expect(wrapper.length.toBe(0));
})
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not handle error in your test cases. Instead you should expect the code to throw errors.

You code should look something like this

```
test('Grid should throw when data is not passed',()=>{
  expect(() => shallow(<Grid/>)).toThrow();
})
```

But ideally, when the right prop is not there, the component should not throw, instead, it should not render.